# How cin change the declared size of string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

i am trying to set my own size to string array. how `cin` overwrite the size of string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int size; cin>>size;
  char str[size];
  cout << "Enter a string: ";
  cin>> str;
  cout << "string size: " << strlen(str);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
5
Enter a string: hellobaby
string size: 9
```

Comment: `size` is the size you reserve for a string of length up to `size -1`. `size` might be 1024 while the length of `”test”` is 4 (plus one for ending null); the remaining 1019 characters are unused. Read about null-terminated strings.

Comment: That's something of an apples-to-oranges comparison. The size of the array holding a null-terminated string and the size of the null-terminated string are independent, unrelated quantities. *(Ideally the relation `string size < array size` holds, but it doesn't have to. That's a big reason why [`std::gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets) was removed in C++14.)* So `cin` does not really overwrite the size of anything. Perhaps you could rephrase the question to ask why `cin` is not limited by the size of the array?

Answer (score 3):

Here you create a [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) with size 5 (given the input in the question:

```
int size;
cin >> size;
char str[size];
```

You then go ahead and enter a string that is longer than that:

```
cin>> str; // hellobaby
```

That string is now written out of bounds so your program has undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Instead of using non-standard VLA:s, you could use a `std::string`

```
#include <string>

unsigned size;
cin >> size;
std::string str;
cin >> str;
str.resize(std::min(str.size(), size));
```

Comment: C++20 adds protection against this kind of out-of-bound reads: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: @HolyBlackCat True. I'm guessing OP isn't using C++20 yet since it's writing out of bounds - or perhaps it doesn't work with VLA:s. I'm not that good with VLA:s.

Comment: Imho nobody should be "good with VLAs" 